# Post Hoc procedures for two-way repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc, two-way

I have a simple 2x2 block of data which I analyzed with a two-way repeated mesures ANOVA. Now I need to do a post-hoc procedureAfter reading some articles, Tukey's HSD was suggested as the less conservative option and t-test with Bonferroni's correction as a safer (more conservative) option. However, it seems to me that by giving up the pairing of data, you lose too much statistical power (like using a t-test when you should be using a paired t-test). Is this true? Is there any way to get around it?